# MSSQL Returning #Error from SCCM report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sccm

I am trying to use the DateDiff expression to compare how many days its been since the last logon timestamp. But when I run the report it returns '#error' in the column.

The Query that I am running is: 
`select  distinct SMS_R_System.Name0,SMS_R_System.Last_Logon_Timestamp0 from vSMS_R_System AS SMS_R_System`

Now that gets me the Name and the LLT (Last Logon Timestamp) but not the 'days idle'. So I created the 'days idle' field: `=Now()` and that returns the systems time just fine. Which is what I would like.

Now to the error. The field textbox holder is capable of holding an expression so you would think that `Now minus LLT` would make sense. But that returns the error. The exact expression for it is: `=DateDiff("dd",Fields!Today.Value,Fields!Last_Logon_Timestamp0.Value)`
I have tried the following too:

Textbox holder

`=DateDiff("dd",Today(),Fields!Last_Logon_Timestamp0.Value)`
`=DateDiff("dd",Now(),Fields!Last_Logon_Timestamp0.Value)`

Same goes for the Field but with the texbox holder just displaying `[Days_idle]` and `[SUM(Days_Idle)]`

Found out that the data in the `v_R_System` table is returning Datetime yyyy-mm-dd hh-mi-ss.mmmm it looks like i need to convert `now()` to that format. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out.
The is my query statement:

`select  distinct SMS_R_System.Name0,SMS_R_System.Last_Logon_Timestamp0,DATEDIFF(DAY,SMS_R_System.Last_Logon_Timestamp0,getdate()) from vSMS_R_System AS SMS_R_System1`

That returns the days its been inactive that i need.